# ProgressBar в WebView

Tags: java, android

Как отследить нажатие внутри `WebView` что бы сделать `ProgressBar` пока грузится другая страничка

Comment: простите, но причем тут нажатия внутри WebView до статуса загрузки страницы? может вы хотите отреагировать на начало загрузки страницы?

Comment: @mirypoko Когда загружается стартовая страничка все хорошо но по нажатию на ссылку она долго грузится и создается впечатление что телефон завис , вот хотелось бы сделать прогрес бар что бы ыбо понятно что все работает и загружается

Comment: попробуйте использовать событие onPageStarted для запуска прогресс бара

Comment: Пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8467430

Answer (score 0):

В методе **onCreate()**, где вы инициализируете ваш `WebView`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

web_view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
web_view.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
web_view.loadUrl("https://example.com/abc");

progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Загрузка...");
progressDialog.show();
}
```

**WebViewClient:**

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);

    if (!progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Ответ взят c [SO.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16292217/5797206)